# @injection of constructor is not work in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use Hilt to inject a data structure but the compilor said:

`@HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor.`

I do not understand why, maybe I misused some of the code for Hilt.

Here is my vieWModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AccountProfileViewModel @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userProfile: UserProfileMemorySource
```

The `UserProfileMemorySource` looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class UserProfileMemorySource @Inject constructor() : UserProfileInterface{

    private var userProfile: UserProfile? = null

    override fun getUserProfile(): UserProfile? {
        return this.userProfile
    }

    override fun saveUserProfile(userProfile: UserProfile?) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile
    }

    override fun invalidate() {
        userProfile = null
    }

}
```

and the data class use is

```
data class UserProfile(
    val name: UserName? = null,
    val email: String = "",
    val phone: String = "",
    val address: Address? = null,
    val url: String = ""
)
```

I am trying to save data into memory.

Any idea why it's not working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies should be passed through the constructor

```
@HiltViewModel
class AccountProfileViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userProfile: UserProfileMemorySource
) { 
...
}
```